# How to write Multiple time frame code for below limited fisher transform indicator in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

How to code Multitime frame for the following code:

```
indicator(title="Limited Fisher Transform", shorttitle="LFish", format=format.price, max_labels_count = 500)
len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")
top = input.int(80, minval=50, title="Upper limit")
bot = input.int(20, maxval=50, title="Lower limit")
round_(val) => val > .99 ? .999 : val < -.99 ? -.999 : val

f_fiisher() =>
high_ = ta.highest(hl2, len)
low_ = ta.lowest(hl2, len)
value = 0.0
value := round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / (high_ - low_) - .5) + .67 * nz(value[1]))
fish1 = 0.0
fish1 := .5 * math.log((1 + value) / (1 - value)) + .5 * nz(fish1[1])
```

I can covert fisher lines upto here using the following:

```
mtfFiisher1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, f_fiisher(), gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
mtfFiisher2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, nz(f_fiisher()[1]), gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

However, how can I code for below lines in multi time frame?

```
y = math.abs(fish1)
n = bar_index
m = n<len? 1 : math.min(n-len+1,500)

t = ta.wma(y,m)//ta.cum(y)/n
f = 100-100/(math.pow(1+1/t,fish1)+1)

fish2 = f[1]
plot(fish2, color = color.orange)
plot(f, color= #2962ff)
buy = ta.crossover(ta.change(f),0) and f<bot
sell = ta.crossunder(ta.change(f),0) and f>top
label.new(ta.valuewhen(buy, bar_index,0),ta.valuewhen(buy,f,0), text = "Buy", color = color.green, style = label.style_label_upper_left,
 textcolor = color.white, size = size.small)
label.new(ta.valuewhen(sell, bar_index,0),ta.valuewhen(sell,f,0), text = "Sell", color = color.red, style = label.style_label_lower_left,
 textcolor = color.white, size = size.small)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In simple language, I want to convert https://www.tradingview.com/script/izxFcflv-Limited-Fisher-Transform/ code to Multi time frame where 80 being overbought level and 20 being oversold level in MTF as well. When trying to use request.security to convert it to multi time frame, it changes the oscillator to go negative as oversold region and does not oscillate between 0 to 100.